# How can I load contacts and filter it out in Elsa SendEmail Activity by extended with my custom activity

Tags: asp.net-core, workflow, elsa-workflows, custom-activity

I wanna build a Marketing Tool so the first module is to build up the Bulk Email through Elsa on all my database table contacts.

so Is anyone here who has built that type of workflow with bulk email on all contacts we can also filter contacts and stop the workflow after running.

So I want to upload the contacts here and run the workflow, Also I didn't find a way to run the workflow from Dashboard.

[image]

[image]

This is a custom activity I have created and extended Elsa SendEmail
I have used "ActivityInput" as JavaScript, Liquid, Json but how can I upload the Contacts CSV file or load from Database all contacts and apply some filter on it.

There is one more question, how can I invoke Workflow via the dashboard?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can get your filters from the UI and query the database for the contacts on your activity execution. I guess your contacts would change on each execution so you should not get the contacts in your activity configuration.